# Cron dosen't sending newsletter

Tags: magento2, email, cron, newsletter

I run manually cron via **cron:run** first I got the error that email address isn't valid when I correct that, now in cron.log I don get nothing about newsletter sending, I don't receive the email either.

I am using Magento 2.3 v